# Pick cloud service for infrequent large cloud computations

Tags: cloud

> Shortly: need 50 cloud VMs for 10 minutes occasionally, 1–2 times per
>   day.

The task is to process hundreds GBs of data. Data is in small chunks and all the processing code is implemented and ready to be scaled from one to hundreds of cores. Average dataset takes 10 minutes to process on 50VMs (each with 16+GB RAM, total of 200 cores).

Processing tasks are infrequent and unpredictable (per user request), so there is no point in keeping cloud VMs always on.

However, most cloud services are slow to scaling, so "10 minutes on 50 VMs" turn to 30+ minutes, wasting time on VMs fire up — and even in that case, resources are not used 100%, because when last VMs are finally online, the task is already processed. After that comes period of "full wasting", when these VMs shutdown for another 30+ minutes, but are still billed.

Is there any known cloud service capable of quickly launching and stopping 50 VMs for such task? Preferably, with transparent pricing.

Comment: This is off-topic for StackOverflow - you're asking for a tool/service recommendation. This isn't a programming question, and cannot be answered objectively.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I disagree: there is no tool observable currently that fits requirements, so it is easy to provide objective answer -- just name the tool that fits the needs.

Comment: @DavidMakogon more than that -- I don't see how this question is "not programming": I am a programmer in need of such solution for the project.

Comment: Yes but you're asking for which cloud to use. Not a programming question. It's a vendor selection question. And it's easy enough to go survey the various vendors to see what they offer. And... with few exceptions, we're all programmers here; that doesn't alter what constitutes off-topic.

Comment: `if your question generally covers… software tools commonly used by programmers … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!`

Comment: `asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic` -- I am not asking for any these. I need a solution to current problem, which is right now implemented not in a best way, as described in question. Also, this question does not `attract opinionated answers and spam` -- HakRou's answer seems helpful.

Comment: Also, why would you remove azure, aws and G. cloud tags from this question, effectivley blocking experts from these areas from providing answers? Seems very unfriendly to me.

Comment: No body is comparing any vendors here. Rustem has a technical need, and the answers can provide a solution for that in a very objective way. This is not about saying which provider is better or worse. It's about solving a problem. If this question is off topic for your, then IMHO, there is no place for such tags as cloud, AWS, Azure, GCP or any others in Stackoverflow, which would defeat the purpose of this website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your jobs are fault tolerent, you can use Google Cloud's preemptible instances. There are instances that last up to 24 hours, then they are automatically shutdown, and are about 70% cheaper than normal instances.

If the machine is shutdown in less than 10 minutes, it's free.
Plus, Google Cloud's instances are the fastest to spin up amongst all the other providers that I used (including AWS). Spin up usually takes about less than 30 seconds.

For more info :

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible

In order to spin up many instances at once, you can do the following :

1 - Create an instance, install all the necessary software you need for your batches.

2 - Create an image from this instance that you can reuse

3 - Create a new instance template using that image, and specify that you need preemtible instances. Now any instance you create from this template will be ready to work. This is very easy to do, since creating a template looks pretty much like creating a unique instance.

4 - Make an instance group based on that template. When doing that, you can specify the number of instance you need (50 in your case). GCP will then spin them at once.

5 - Now can kill them yourself when you want, or you can leave them be, and they will live up to 24 hours and will be killed automatically. You can change the number of instances in the instance group whenever you want.

More info :
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible#preemptible_with_instance_groups

This is the simplest and cleanest way to go. You only need to do it once and then it will be a matter of a few clicks to spin your instances anytime you need them.

Another way would be to write a little script that will loop and create an instance, 50 times.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Now that's something! Do you think it's possible to create sets of 50 preemtptible instances on a daily basis?

Comment: sure, I've updated the answer with more details on how to do that.

Answer (score -1):

You can consider using the Azure Batch service which is designed for High Performance Compute (HPC).
It's meant to run compute-intensive tasks on 100s or 100s of VM and scale automatically. You can have them run on-demand or based on a schedule. You pay once the VMs are ready to start running your tasks.

Here are some useful introductory links

1. [Azure Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-technical-overview)
2. [Short introductory video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/Introduction-to-Azure-Batch-with-Mark-Scurrell) (a bit old)
3. [Longer more recent video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/P411)

Azure Batch is meant for HPC so you should first consider whether your job falls in that category and requires those kind of resources.

I am not aware of the other cloud platforms so can't help you there.

Comment: Azure Batch has all downsides, that I mentioned in my questions: it is not designed to quickly fire up loads of VMs on demand. It is designed to handle constant HPC load... Please let me know, if I am wrong.

Comment: In fact you can dynamically add/remove compute nodes based on your parameters, by specifying formulas.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-automatic-scaling

Comment: can I create formula to scale it 0 to 50 nodes and back to 0 when processing done (in 10 minutes)? How fast will it scale up and down?

Comment: `Autoscaling is not currently intended to respond to changes in less than a minute, but rather is intended to adjust the size of your pool gradually as you run a workload.` Minimal scale threshold is 5 minutes, what means my processing time will be doubled (or tripled, if it takes at least 10 minutes to fire up)

Comment: It is then a matter of deciding the optimal pool size for the average task and using that as the start size. No matter how you scale there will be some time involved in spinning up a new VM. I don't see how you can avoid that.